# Open the website when a youtube video is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, load

I have this auto play youtube video embedded in the background on the top page, and what I'm trying to do is that keep the loading page going until the video is fully loaded so that people can see it playing when they go in. The problem here is that the loading page opens even though the video is still in the middle of loading.

I've set up the load function for the loading page assuming that it does things once the page is loaded? Is there way to detect if the youtube video is fully loaded with this load function?

Here is the js code for youtube

```
if(!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android)/)){

  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('top_video', {
      width: '100%',
      videoId: 'ZHe75UFH6uE',
      playerVars : {
            'loop' : 1,
            'autoplay' : 1,
            'mute' : 1,
            'rel' : 0,
            'showinfo' : 0,
            'controls' : 0,
            'modestbranding' : 1,
            'iv_load_policy' : 3,
            'cc_load_policy' : 1,
            'origin': location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + "/"
        },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  var interval_is_stopped = false;
        setInterval(function (){
          var current_time = event.target.getCurrentTime();

          if (current_time > 81.9 && !interval_is_stopped) {
            interval_is_stopped = true;
            jQuery('#top_video').fadeTo(400, 0.7, function(){
              player.seekTo(0);
              jQuery(this).fadeTo(400, 1, function(){
                interval_is_stopped = false;
              });
            });
          }
        }, 10);
}

 var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data==YT.PlayerState.CUED && !done) {
          done = true;
        }
      }

  $('#pauseplay').on('click', function(){
    var isMuted = player.isMuted();
    if( $(this).hasClass('sound_off_active') && isMuted ){
      $(this).removeClass('sound_off_active');
      $(this).addClass('sound_on_active');
      player.unMute();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('sound_off_active');
      $(this).removeClass('sound_on_active');
      player.mute();
    }

  });


$(function () {
    $('a.disabled').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

}
```

and here is the loading js

```
var $delayTime = 3000;

$(window).on('load', function(){

    var $loadingAnim = $('.loadingAnim'),
        $body = $('body');

    setTimeout( function(){

        $body.addClass('loaded');

        $loadingAnim.find('.loadingAnim_line').on('transitionend', function( e ){
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });

    }, $delayTime );
});
```

This is my website

https://www.run-journey.com/

and I need to show a video like in this website

https://re-creation.co.jp/

Comment: Add the event `'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange` to your settings and when fired set a global variable like `stateChanged` to true and load the page accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited the code like above and I don't know how to load the page in a way you explained. Do I have to set up the condition to see if the done variable is true and wrap the whole loading js part with it? I know that the done variable is not global so I can not use it for the loading js..I'm sorry I'm still a beginner in javascript.

Comment: Close, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18221111/3990896). Ultimately you will have to play with css and js to show or hide elements accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer you gave me is completely irrelevant. I'm trying not to do anything with image when the video ends. All I need to know is if I can detect if the video is loaded and play the video right away once the loading page is opened. I don't know how to explain this well so please check my website again and see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would drop the set timeout and let the animation run until the video is loaded (cued), something like:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {    
    if(event.data === 5) {          
        hideAnimation();
    }
}

function hideAnimation() {
    $('.loadingAnim').find('.loadingAnim_line').on('transitionend', function (e) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
}
```

More information about the state of the player [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getPlayerState).

Comment: I figured this out in the way you explained above. Thank you so much.